# I'm trying to animate a character's hair programatically. What's the best approach for this?

Tags: 3d, three.js, unity-game-engine, blender

I've programmed a cloth simulation in JavaScript ([see link](http://maia.im/cloth)) that I would like to use to control the hair and clothes of a character programatically. That is, I'd "pin" some vectors on the mesh, get the pivot points on real time based on movement/gravity/forces and then apply those to the mesh. I'm not using custom cloth simulators because they don't give me the full control I need.

What is the best approach to apply the vectors I generated on the mesh? Should I use bones or what? I'm trying to do it using Three.js, but it wasn't made for that. Is there a proper tool for what I'm trying to do? What I am trying to do, actually?

Answer (score 3):

Hair management in 3d is a very difficult task that mixes a lot of simulation with a lot of fakery.  If all you need is a little bit of movement to make a conventional hair mesh look less than static you can use a highly damped soft body simulator with pinned points.  However this will rarely look very realistic - it's merely less unrealistic than helmet hair.  Realistic hair rendering is a very complex business - [this pdf from Disney](http://disney-animation.s3.amazonaws.com/library/artDirectHair11.pdf) gives a good example of the lengths that film production has to go to (the same website also has good references on hair rendering, which is not handled well by standard shading models)

A common trick in VFX rendering is to simulate a subset of the strands and then interpolate the rest between nearby simulated ones. This keeps the computation costs within reason. You could try that - simulating guide hairs as simple bone chains and the drawing a b-spline through the joints in the chain, then using the guide splines as the basis for a larger number of interpolated ones. Depending on your renderer these splines could be rendered as line segments or textured ribbons with an alpha texture to give them the right look.  Here's [an example of the limited simulation approach in Blender](http://www.blendernation.com/2011/12/19/hair-collision-in-blender-2-61/)

However, it's hard to imagine doing a thorough hair sim in JS, the simulation is very time consuming.  It's not commonly done in real time: you'll notice that very few current generation games do hair or detailed cloth simulations in real time.

The usual film/tv approach is to create a hand-edited set of guide (both splines to direct the hair and 'force fields' to shape it) and then run a lengthy offline simulation. [Maya](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p7nCndZKvVs), for example, includes hair rendering but most productions that really care use dedicated plugins like [Shave And A Haircut](http://www.joealter.com/shave.htm).